# How can I get a list of Credit Cards from Dynamics GP?

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp, econnect

Is there a way to get a list of existing credit cards in GP using eConnect?

Current implementation uses the .NET serialization approach mentioned in the eConnect documentation, though I haven't been able to find any information about how to get a list of currently existing credit cards.

Some methods exist for creating new cards within GP, but what I'd really like to get a list of the existing cards (along with their names) so that I can send in credit card information on newly created invoices (using the CRCRDAMNT / CCAMPYNM / CARDNAME headers).

Am I out of luck on this one?

Answer (score 0):

payment information is in SOP10103 table, just shoot a select query based on your criteria.

or if you are using gp web service then sales order object also returns information about payment (salesOrder.Payments)

hope it helps !